# Matplotlib: Line2D height in pixels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have for instance the following line drawn in matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1) # two rows, one column, first plot
# This should be a straight line which spans the y axis
# from 0 to 50
line, = ax.plot([0]*50, range(50), color='blue', lw=2)
line2, = ax.plot([10]*100, range(100), color='blue', lw=2)
```

how can I get how many pixels that straight line is, in the y direction?

Note: I have several of these lines with gaps in between and I would like to put text next to them, however, if there are too many lines, I would need to know how much text I can add, that is the reason why I need the height of the line.

For instance in the attached photo, there is a blue line on the right hand side which is roughly 160 pixels in height. In a height of 160 pixels (with the font I am using) I can fit in roughly 8 lines of text as the height of the text is roughly 12 pixels in height.

How can I get the information on how tall the line is in pixels? Or is there a better way to lay the text out?

[image: Text next to a straight line]

Comment: thanks for the comment will do.

Comment: This is specifically for pixels for straight lines, not splines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to obtain the height of a line in units of pixels you can use its bounding box. To make sure the bounding box is the one from the line as drawn on the canvas, you first need to draw the canvas. Then the bounding box is obtained via `.line2.get_window_extent()`. The difference between the upper end of the bounding box (`y1`) and the lower end (`y0`) is then the number of pixels you are looking for.

```
fig.canvas.draw()
bbox = line2.get_window_extent(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
# at this point you can get the line height:
print "Lineheight in pixels: ", bbox.y1 - bbox.y0
```

In order to draw text within the y-extent of the line, the following may be useful. Given a fontsize in points, e.g. `fontsize = 12`, you may calculate the size in pixels and then calculate the number of possible text lines to fit into the range of pixels determined above. Using a blended transform, where where x is in data units and y in pixels allows you to specify the x-coordinate in data units (here `x=8`) but the y coordinate in a coordinate in pixels calculated from the extent of the line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1) 

line, = ax.plot([0]*50, range(50), color='blue', lw=2)
line2, = ax.plot([10]*100, range(100), color='blue', lw=2)

fig.canvas.draw()
bbox = line2.get_window_extent(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
# at this point you can get the line height:
print "Lineheight in pixels: ", bbox.y1 - bbox.y0

#To draw text
fontsize=12 #pt
# fontsize in pixels:
fs_pixels = fontsize*fig.dpi/72.
#number of possible texts to draw:
n = (bbox.y1 - bbox.y0)/fs_pixels
# create transformation where x is in data units and y in pixels
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, transforms.IdentityTransform())
for i in range(int(n)):
    ax.text(8.,bbox.y0+(i+1)*fs_pixels, "Text", va="top", transform=trans)


plt.show()
```

[image]